# About password ciphertext

Tags: encryption, passwords, hash, decryption

I need to decrypt a password. I have the ciphertext for this
however, I have many plain text and encrypted equivalents.

This device can only be given passwords with a maximum of 8 characters from the 0123456789abcdef alphabet, and it can be less than 8.

The default password is 12345678 and this is the encrypted equivalent.
"bİ.JaN.ù" or in hex 62 DD 8E 4A 61 4E 1A F9

Even if the password is less than 8 characters, the ciphertext is still as long as described above.

Can I detect the encryption type or is it hash?

This is the ciphertext of the password I want to know
"‡ ?>ìK®p"  or in hex 87 A0 3F 3E EC 4B AE 70

Can I get the password from this ciphertext?

Comment: What's a "chippertext"? And the edit doesn't make this different from the duplicate. We aren't a decryption service, and standard encryption is designed to not be crackable.

Comment: So the other question didn't do my job so I asked another question. Also the other question is about encryption. Do not contradict yourself. The other question is allowed, as for me, are you saying this is not a decryption service?

Comment: @furkan The other question is an exception, it has been kept by the community as a *canonical question*. We direct all people asking similar question to it, because the answers there also provide help on how to handle the general case of trying to identify unknown "encryption". In the end, it is usually impossible to conclusively identify/decrypt a random piece of encrypted data, which is why we close all such questions and point people to the canonical post.

Comment: @furkan the duplicate is asking how to do something in general. You are asking how to crack ***this specific string***. There is no contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for spend time. I am sory for this. :)